# TextBox HideSelection in XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml, textbox, selection

Is there any way to do the equivalent of TextBox.HideSelection=false in WPF?
The code below is as close as I can get it - where you need to "tab" through the fields to get them to show up.
I need the selections to at least all show when the button is pressed.
(My actual application is binding to selectionstart/length settings)
(also: any other control that allows range highlighting would be fine too!)
Thanks for any help!

```
<Window x:Class="selectionbrush.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
        <Setter Property="IsInactiveSelectionHighlightEnabled" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="IsReadOnly" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5"/>
        <Setter Property="SelectionBrush" Value="Green"/>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <MultiTrigger>
                <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Condition Property="IsSelectionActive" Value="false"/>
                </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <Setter Property="SelectionBrush" Value="Red"/>
            </MultiTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<StackPanel>
    <Button Content="set selections" Click="Button_Click" Margin="5" MaxWidth="100" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Padding="5,0,5,0"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="tb1" SelectionStart="1" SelectionLength="8" Text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, agam dolore mediocritatem eu qui"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="tb2" SelectionStart="5" SelectionLength="3" Text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, agam dolore mediocritatem eu qui"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="tb3" SelectionStart="9" SelectionLength="12" Text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, agam dolore mediocritatem eu qui"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="tb4" SelectionStart="4" SelectionLength="9" Text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, agam dolore mediocritatem eu qui"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="tb5" SelectionStart="11" SelectionLength="4" Text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, agam dolore mediocritatem eu qui"/>
</StackPanel>
```

with this in the codebehind:

```
        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        tb1.SelectionStart = 6; tb1.SelectionLength = 5;
        tb2.SelectionStart = 17; tb2.SelectionLength = 7;
        tb3.SelectionStart = 8; tb3.SelectionLength = 8;
        tb4.SelectionStart = 12; tb4.SelectionLength = 3;
        tb5.SelectionStart = 14; tb5.SelectionLength = 9;
    }
```

Comment: It seems impossible with TextBox - I'm going to use a RichTextBox instead...

Answer (score 0):

It seems impossible with TextBox - I'm going to use a RichTextBox instead...

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub TextBox_LostFocus(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
        e.Handled = True
    'This keeps the selected text visible by setting handled equal to TRUE
End Sub
```